# C# dotnet apps equivalent of shared preference of Android?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am building a dotnet app and I need to store simple variables for later use. I also need that to be stored safely so that its not sitting around in a folder and user accidentally deletes it. I can use levelDB. But it has no encryption, and the db files are put in a unsafe place. I can use sqlite, about which I'm not sure about db files placement.

So what is a good solution for dotnet UWP apps on windows or any platform that is either equivalent to shared preference or datastore of Android?

Comment: This isn't a C# question or even a .NET question. It's basically a Windows question.

Comment: @John Such can a UWP app, thus saying only windows is not correct